# ExecutorService cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: java, android, executorservice, dagger-hilt

I am getting this error however I have already provided the executor to my Appmodule (Dagger Hilt)

```
@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("Single")
public ExecutorService provideSingleExecutor() { return Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); }

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named("FixedSize")
public ExecutorService provideFixedSizeExecutor() { return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3); }
```

I have not gotten any such error with any of my other Singletons

The ExecutorServices are being injected by the constructor

Could someone please explain a possible cause and solution

https://github.com/infinum/Dagger-2-Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/co/infinum/pokemon/dagger/modules/DefaultExecutorsModule.java

Here it was added in the same way

Comment: Did you add @InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class) annotation to your Appmodule?

Comment: Yes I did, https://github.com/E5c11/TicTacToe_3D/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/esc/test/apps/dagger/AppModule.java,
All my other singletons work perfectly.

Comment: There is no provide methods for ExecutorService in your AppModule. Add provide methods for ExecutorService to your AppModule

Comment: That is not the updated commit, my code in the question shows you how I added it

Comment: Did you add @Named("Single") or @Named("FixedSize") annotation to constructor of class where you injected ExecutorService?

Comment: Yes, for both variants

Comment: If it doesn't work, then I will simply just use a (non-injected) singleton.